# Exhaustive categorisation of errors for dynamic memory management

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

When coding in C++ without the use of smart pointers, I sometimes face memory errors. I am trying to categorize all possible memory errors, so that it helps me better understand and prevent them.
So far I can see 3 possible categories:

1) Using an object AFTER it has been deleted (=> undefined behavior)

2) Not freeing up memory after all pointers to it are out of scope (=> memory leak)

3) Calling delete on the same memory twice, for example deleting an array, and then an object that was in this array (=> heap corruption)

What else is there?

Comment: To help prevent those errors, use smart pointers

Comment: As I said this is when I code without smart pointers. I often work on codebases that I have not created from scratch myself (as I'm sure you are as well), and therefore cannot always decide to not use regular pointers.

Comment: 4) Cycles with `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I was trying to categorize errors when not using smart pointers, but it is still interesting to point this out.